# How to make a function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which I want it to convert it to function so that I can use it in where clause. The problem in that my procedure return multiple column up to 3. Also on the basis of input parameters the row can be varied from 1 to 3. It takes two dates(start date and end date) as input of data type 'date'.

I can post the output of my procedure-

Output-1

```
Type               Start date              End date                             
  1                 20150607               20150701
```

Output-2

```
Type               Start date               End date                             
  1                 20150603               20150607
  2                 2015071                2015083
  1                 20150817               20150820
```

Output-3

```
Type               Start date               End date                             
  1                 20150607             20150630
  3                 201507               201509
  1                 20151001             20151008
```

I posted 3 of my procedure output there are more but they are similar of like this only.

Now in the where clause I want to use this start date and end date of each row with its type.

Type is nothing but the day type whether its a day level info or week level info or month level info

```
1 is  day level info
2 is  week level info
3 is  month level info
```

How can use that start date and end date in where clause as dates between for each row of dates that is returned by procedure?

I want help on this as there are different type of function and which one is suitable for my requirement. What changes I have to make it to make a function from procedure?

Comment: look at table-valued functions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/26/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-table-valued-functions-day-26-of-35/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return a table with all the columns you need, for example:

Function

CREATE FUNCTION ufn_RetImages (@Date varchar(8))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    select 
        ImageBildID as ImageBildID, 
        convert(varchar,DateCaptured_SD, 112) as dateT 
    from 
        dbo.ImageBild_T
    where
    convert(varchar,DateCaptured_SD, 112) = @Date
);

and after call the function using the parameters necessaries

select * from dbo.ufn_RetImages('20130612')